# GROUP BY mysql showing only one row. But want repetitions also

Tags: php, mysql, database

My table structure is

```
id  order_id  location time    date
 1   951        x              2/03/2013
 2   951        x      13:00   2/03/2013
 3   951        y              3/03/2013
```

I want to show these in php with group by date something like

```
Date 2/03/2013
Orderid 951 location x
Orderid 951 location x

Date 3/03/2013
Orderid 951 location y
```

mysql query im performing is

```
select * from table where order_id=951 GROUP BY date ORDER BY id ASC
```

But this query only return the first row of same data . How can i show all the repetition in group by date category. how to use it in php to show data by taking date as separate variable.

i am editing question to let you know that date can be anything i just want order id to show by date in group including repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show all rows in the table, better to `ORDER BY date, id` then do the grouping in PHP.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from table ORDER BY data ASC,id ASC");
$last_date = "";
while(($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
{
    if($last_date != $row['date'])
    {
        echo "Date " . $row['date'] . "\n";
    }
    echo "Orderid ". $row['order_id']." location " . $row['location']. "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah that can be done. but is there any mysql way to perform this. even if i order by id . Its still in ascending order by date as the data is added after previous time. And i dont thing grouping in php with respect to date is robust way. if the data is too much grouping in php would be a problem. Am i right.

Comment: @AbhishekGahlot see my answer for ordering your date in asc format

Comment: Tragically, `$last_date` is not updated inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `STR_TO_DATE()` function for ordering by date

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC, id ASC");
$last_date = "";
while(($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
{
    if($last_date != $row['date'])
    {
        echo "Date " . $row['date'] . "\n";
    }
    echo "Orderid ". $row['order_id']." location " . $row['location']. "\n";
}
```

Comment: if you want to order date you have to use `STR_TO_DATE()` function in your query

Comment: Tragically, `$last_date` is not updated inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where order_id=951 ORDER BY date DESC, id ASC
```

And then manipulate from PHP

Order By will not return rows inside grouping. If you really wanted to use sql then you try GROUP_CONCAT which returns grouped row values as a concatenated string and later split it from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Since your table owned the `time` column maybe you should consider inside your query, order is default by ascending, so you can skip for writing `asc`.

```
select * from table where order_id=951 order by date,time,id;
```

You can create a global php variable to store the current date you read, compare everytime in the while loop, and if it's different from the global one, print something to separate from the last group.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

`select date,group_concat("Location " , location, "\n")  from table where order_id=951 GROUP BY date ORDER BY id ASC`